# Benefits of multiplication rather than division

Tags: sql, performance, floating-point

Recently someone suggested to me that division is always more expensive than multiplication.
As a consequence when designing a database it may be beneficial to store 2 columns in such a away that a 3rd field can be recovered by multiplying the first two, rather than dividing the first two.

Am I correct to believe that this is **not** necessarily true for operations that are pipelined.
I would expect my database engine to vectorise my operations and then pipeline them. Therefore I would expect the cost of division to be heavily offset by the fact that I need to do so many -> Multiplying a million pairs of rows should only take a few tens of cycles longer than dividing a million pairs of rows

Comment: Division is usually costlier than multiplication, but this depends on many factors.  Can you let us know what exact database you are using (e.g. MySQL,SQL Server, etc.) ?

Comment: I use both Postgres and SQL Server. What kinds of factors are we talking about?

Comment: I just read that some databases will internally convert the operation into the product of the inverse of what was to be divided, hence the operation won't take any longer.

Comment: You can materialize the result if You need more speed.